# Angular Ionic url resolve from http://localhost:8100/login to http://localhost:8100

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on angular ionic pwa application and my login page url is coming as http://localhost:8100/login and I want to resolve to **http://localhost:8100** so that it will look better in production like fb.com or twitter.com.

Thanks

Comment: Share routing configuration.

Comment: const routes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: 'post', pathMatch: 'full' },
   

 {
      path: 'login',
      loadChildren: () => import('./webhome/webhome.module').then(m => m.WebhomePageModule)
    },
    {
      path: 'post',
      loadChildren: () => import('./feed/feed.module').then(m => m.FeedPageModule),
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  
    },
   
  ];

Comment: As i can see, you are redirecting to post when using this url http://localhost:8100. So now you want to redirect to login page instead of post ? Is that your question?

Comment: Hello, yes I am routing to post but if user is not logged in I am routing to login page (navigate('/login')) and it is adding /login which I want to avoid as this is my base url of site and will have login /signup button which some other details on the page. My site url https://stockaro.com/..please check on hitting this it is navigating to https://stockaro.com/login.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can redirect the user to the `login` page when they hit baseurl and redirect them to the `\post` page if already logged in.

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
           { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
           { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./webhome/webhome.module').then(m => m.WebhomePageModule) }, 
           { path: 'post', loadChildren: () => import('./feed/feed.module').then(m => m.FeedPageModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
      ];
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried above solution but after hitting base url again it is routing to login and /login to base url. Just take a look fb.com, they doesn't add any page url in their base url. I wanted like that.